# If input field is empty run condition, otherwise run condition 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works just fine, the only problem is when I delete all the characters from the input and press the "send" button, "Field required" doesn't show up, and the "Minimum 8 characters" message remains.

I hope you guys can help me out, cheers.

```js
$(function() {

  var elInput = $('#username');
  var message = $('.msg');

  $('#send').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!elInput.val()) {
      message.addClass('msg2');
    } else {
      if(elInput.val().length < 8) {
        message.css({
          'color': 'grey',
          'display': 'inline'
        }).text('Minimum 8 characters');
      } else {
      message.css('display', 'none');
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.msg {
  display: none;
}
.msg2 {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Validation Form</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="username">Name</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username"><br/>
    <span class="msg">Field required</span><br/>

    <button id="send">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: how you get elInput value?

Comment: Try `if(!elInput.val().trim())` to remove whitespace, or more explicitly `if(elInput.val().length == 0)`. Also where have you defined `elInput`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the relevant HTML and the rest of the script.

Comment: You would bind to the `keyup` event in this case

Comment: Edited. Also I've tried .trim() and .length == 0, but same issue

Comment: This works: https://jsfiddle.net/8hjk65ka/ You have a typo with the vat message as well.

Comment: @tavozapata, you should consider that in javascript as an empty string could be converted in a boolean false value, a non empty string is always true, when converted to a boolean. Even it is a string with spaces. Using trim remove the spaces and made the string empty. If is became not false, you should check what the val exatly is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this :

```
if(elInput.val().length == 0) {
        message.css({
          'color': 'grey',
          'display': 'inline'
        }).text('Required');
```

and edit this :

```
if(elInput.val().length < 8 && elInput.val().length != 0) {
    message.css({
      'color': 'grey',
      'display': 'inline'
    }).text('Minimum 8 characters');
```

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks a lot. But do you know why mine wasn't working?

Comment: @tavozapata Because length < 8 means length==0 too

Comment: But I did this and it worked too: if(!elInput.val()) {
      message.css({
          'color': 'red',
          'display': 'inline'
        }).text('Field required');
    } else {
      if(elInput.val().length < 8) {
        message.css({
          'color': 'grey',
          'display': 'inline'
        }).text('Minimum 8 characters');
      } else {
      message.css('display', 'none');
      }
    }